# SQLAlchemy is taking too long to fetch data as compared to PgAdmin

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pgadmin

I am using SqlAlchemy and PostgreSQL for storing stocks data.

Here is my Schema:

```
from sqlalchemy import DateTime, Column, Integer, String, Float

from base_sql import Base

class StockData(Base):
    __tablename__ = "StocksData"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = Column(DateTime(timezone=False))
    ticker = Column(String(90))
    interval = Column(String(90))
    open = Column(Float())
    high = Column(Float())
    low = Column(Float())
    close = Column(Float())
    volume = Column(Float())

def __int__(self, id, date,ticker, interval, open, high,
            low, close, volume):
    self.id = id
    self.date = date
    self.ticker = ticker
    self.interval = interval
    self.open = open
    self.high = high
    self.low = low
    self.close = close
    self.volume = volume
```

I have pushed around 4M rows to my Database. Now I am trying to access the data I pushed using SQLAlchemy using this code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from price_data_sql import StockData
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

import time

from base_sql import engine, Base, Session

engine = create_engine(os.getenv("POSTGRES_CONNECTION_STRING"))
session = Session()

st = time.time()
print("Querying database...")
query = session.query(StockData).all()
print(f"Query took {time.time() - st} seconds")
session.close()

print(len(query))
```

The output for this code:

```
Querying database...
Query took 58.79122018814087 seconds
4013519
```

However when I run the command "View/Edit > All Rows" in PgAdmin, it takes around **3.5 seconds**. **Could Someone please explain the plausible reason for that?**

Any suggestions on how I can boost up this process?

[image]

Comment: When pg_admin queried the data, is the data cached already? Did it really get all 4 million row out at the same time, or did it get only the first few pages? You can just print out the SQL emitted by SQLAlchemy and pg_admin to see the difference.

Comment: @LouisHuang, Thanks for your response! It is less likely that the data was cached since I restarted the PgAdmin and the duration was 3.5 seconds, however, can you tell me how to check if the data was cached or not? Yes, pgadmin did get all 4m rows, I just had scroll through them. How do I print out SQL emitted by the two?

Comment: @IshaanGupta are you sure that `pgadmin` uses `ORM` when query?